# Finding marginal distribution of $Y$ for $(X,Y)$ given by $f(x,y)=3$

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

**Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}, \: A=\left\{(x, y) \in R^{2} | 0<x<1,0<y<x^{2}\right\}$ be a PMF for the joint r.v. $(X,Y)$ given by $f(x,y)=3$. Find marginal distribution of $Y$.**

Let be denote the marginal distribution of $Y$ as $f_Y$.
This is how I will find it: by calculating the following integral: $f_Y(y)=\int_0^{x^2}3dx$. ***This is apparently wrong***. I can't figure out why?

Comment: You need to integrate over values of x, not y, so limits of integration should be 0 and 1, not 0 and $x^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint density of $(X,Y)$ is
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3\cdot\mathsf 1_A,
$$
so to find the marginal density of $Y$ we integrate over all values of $X$. Hence
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{\sqrt y}^1 3\ \mathsf dx = 3 \left(1-\sqrt{y}\right)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y).
$$

Comment: I realised that I do not know how to find the correct bounds when integrating over $x$. Is far as I can see $x$ lies between 0 and 1, so these should be the bounds. But that's not correct either. How do you find you bound to be $1$ and $\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: $y<x^2$ if and only if $\sqrt y<x$.